# C program to print right angle triangle pattern

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to write a program to display the following:

```
1
23  
345  
4567  
56789  
678901  
7890123  
89012345  
901234567
```

Below is my code:

```
int rows,i,j,k=0;
printf("Enter the height: \n");
scanf("%d",&rows);
printf("The pattern is: \n");
for(i=1;i<=rows;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=i;++j)
        printf("%d",k+j);
    ++k;
    printf("\n");
}
```

However when I input the value of 7, this happens:

```
1   
23   
345    
4567   
56789   
67891011    
78910111213
```

Would need help on tweaking cause I've ran out of brain juice. Thank you!

Comment: So the only problem is you want the last digit printed for 10, 11, 12, and so on instead of the whole number? Do you know any way to find the last digit of a number?

Comment: Hint: `% 10` will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 30;
    
    for(int row=0; row<height; ++row)
    {
        for(int n=0; n<row+1; ++n)
        {
            printf("%d", (n+row+1)%10);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need modulo arithmetic. i.e

Change `k+j` to `(k+j) % 10`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer with only one for-loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height = 23;
    char* text = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
    
    for(int row=0; row<height; ++row)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", row+1, text+row);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not dynamic at all. For height = 500 let's say, will you store a string that is of size 500. That's utter wastage of space.